# Add class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add class to div while creating dynamic input.

```
div.class = "form-group";
```

Not working for me. which is commented in bellow code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dynInput(cbox) {
        if (cbox.checked) {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id = cbox.value;
            //div.class = "form-group";
            div.innerHTML = "<label>Cost Per Test For " + cbox.value + "</label>";
            div.appendChild(input);
            document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);
       } else {
            document.getElementById(cbox.value).remove();
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to change to this:

```
  div.className = "form-group";
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be **[`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)** instead of `class` :

```
div.className = "form-group";
```

You could use **[`classList()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** instead.

> Using *classList* is a convenient alternative to accessing an element's list of classes as a space-delimited string via *element.className*.

```
div.classList.add('form-group');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `addClass()`

```
$(div).addClass('form-group');
```

or create the elements as string and append them using jquery `append()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dynInput(cbox) {
        if (cbox.checked) {
            label = "<label>Cost Per Test For " + cbox.value + "</label>";
            $("#insertinputs").append('<div class="form-group" id="'+cbox.value+'">'+label+'<input type="text"></div>');
       } else {
            $('#'+cbox.value).remove();
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `div.className` not only `.class`